# A better way to define a piecewise constant function

Tags: r, function

I have a vector of values corresponding to a vector of integers, and I'd like to make those discrete points into a continuous constant piecewise function. I did this using `if else if` function in `R`. As the length of both vectors are quite long, it seems silly to define this function manually one by one. I searched online, but `stepfun` function doesn't work in this case, as I need it to be a function of a single variable `x`. Could you suggest a better way to do this? Full code of my original function. This function intends to be used as part of the integrate function for an integral calculation.  Thank you in advance.

```
x = c(0:80)
y = seq(0,18, length.out = length(x))
y.f = function(x){
  if (x>=0 & x<1) {y[1]}
  else if (x>=1 & x<2) {y[2]}
  else if (x>=2 & x<3) {y[3]}
  else if (x>=3 & x<4) {y[4]}
  else if (x>=4 & x<5) {y[5]}
  else if (x>=5 & x<6) {y[6]}
  else if (x>=6 & x<7) {y[7]}
  else if (x>=7 & x<8) {y[8]}
  else if (x>=8 & x<9) {y[9]}
  else if (x>=9 & x<10) {y[10]}
  else if (x>=10 & x<11) {y[11]}
  else if (x>=11 & x<12) {y[12]}
  else if (x>=12 & x<13) {y[13]}
  else if (x>=13 & x<14) {y[14]}
  else if (x>=14 & x<15) {y[15]}
  else if (x>=15 & x<16) {y[16]}
  else if (x>=16 & x<17) {y[17]}
  else if (x>=17 & x<18) {y[18]}
  else if (x>=18 & x<19) {y[19]}
  else if (x>=19 & x<20) {y[20]}
  else if (x>=20 & x<21) {y[21]}
  else if (x>=21 & x<22) {y[22]}
  else if (x>=22 & x<23) {y[23]}
  else if (x>=23 & x<24) {y[24]}
  else if (x>=24 & x<25) {y[25]}
  else if (x>=25 & x<26) {y[26]}
  else if (x>=26 & x<27) {y[27]}
  else if (x>=27 & x<28) {y[28]}
  else if (x>=28 & x<29) {y[29]}
  else if (x>=29 & x<30) {y[30]}
  else if (x>=30 & x<31) {y[31]}
  else if (x>=31 & x<32) {y[32]}
  else if (x>=32 & x<33) {y[33]}
  else if (x>=33 & x<34) {y[34]}
  else if (x>=34 & x<35) {y[35]}
  else if (x>=35 & x<36) {y[36]}
  else if (x>=36 & x<37) {y[37]}
  else if (x>=37 & x<38) {y[38]}
  else if (x>=38 & x<39) {y[39]}
  else if (x>=39 & x<40) {y[40]}
  else if (x>=40 & x<41) {y[41]}
  else if (x>=41 & x<42) {y[42]}
  else if (x>=42 & x<43) {y[43]}
  else if (x>=43 & x<44) {y[44]}
  else if (x>=44 & x<45) {y[45]}
  else if (x>=45 & x<46) {y[46]}
  else if (x>=46 & x<47) {y[47]}
  else if (x>=47 & x<48) {y[48]}
  else if (x>=48 & x<49) {y[49]}
  else if (x>=49 & x<50) {y[50]}
  else if (x>=50 & x<51) {y[51]}
  else if (x>=51 & x<52) {y[52]}
  else if (x>=52 & x<53) {y[53]}
  else if (x>=53 & x<54) {y[54]}
  else if (x>=54 & x<55) {y[55]}
  else if (x>=55 & x<56) {y[56]}
  else if (x>=56 & x<57) {y[57]}
  else if (x>=57 & x<58) {y[58]}
  else if (x>=58 & x<59) {y[59]}
  else if (x>=59 & x<60) {y[60]}
  else if (x>=60 & x<61) {y[61]}
  else if (x>=61 & x<62) {y[62]}
  else if (x>=62 & x<63) {y[63]}
  else if (x>=63 & x<64) {y[64]}
  else if (x>=64 & x<65) {y[65]}
  else if (x>=65 & x<66) {y[66]}
  else if (x>=66 & x<67) {y[67]}
  else if (x>=67 & x<68) {y[68]}
  else if (x>=68 & x<69) {y[69]}
  else if (x>=69 & x<70) {y[70]}
  else if (x>=70 & x<71) {y[71]}
  else if (x>=71 & x<72) {y[72]}
  else if (x>=72 & x<73) {y[73]}
  else if (x>=73 & x<74) {y[74]}
  else if (x>=74 & x<75) {y[75]}
  else if (x>=75 & x<76) {y[76]}
  else if (x>=76 & x<77) {y[77]}
  else if (x>=77 & x<78) {y[78]}
  else if (x>=78 & x<79) {y[79]}
  else if (x>=79 & x<80) {y[80]}
  else if (x>=80 & x<81) {y[81]}
}
y.f(0.005)
```

Comment: Please provide a specific reproducible function.  Do not omit part. of it.  Simplify it instead and show a test of it.  Please read the guidance at the top  of the [tag:r] tag page for more info on asking questions.

Comment: There are several things I'd guard against here, perhaps this is a small programming-soapbox: (1) don't "reach out" and get `y` from inside the function, that's scope breach, and while it works it can render the function a little more difficult to troubleshoot, make `y` a required argument of the function; (2) I suspect (without much reason) that this could be vectorized fairly easily, perhaps reduced completely to `y[ findInterval(x, 0:9) ]` with some more defensive programming (and depending on your intent and actual values).

Comment: It looks like the pattern in your code could be boiled down to a single line `y[ceiling(x)]` with some added checks to make handle cases where x < 0 and x >= 81

Comment: Try `y[floor(x0) + 1]` or `y[findInterval(x0, x)]` where x0 is the input.

Comment: Both ``y.f = function(x){y[ceiling(x)]}
`` and ``y.f = function(x) {y[floor(x) + 1]}`` work! This is magic! Could you explain why this works? Thank you.

Comment: The only difference is when ``x=0``, ``y[ceiling(x)]`` gives numeric(0), while ``y[floor(x) + 1]`` gives 0.

Comment: If you have a non-integer like 5.1 then `ceiling` rounds up to the next int which would be 6 in this case. Your pattern of `(x>=i & x<i+1) {y[i+1]}` is basically just calling the ceiling function on x